# WPF: Bind Collection with Collection to a ListBox with groups

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, grouping, collections

sometimes WPF is too complex for me. I've got my "Window1" holding a collection of "Group"s. "Group" is a class with a collection of "Person"s. In the end this should be a contact list. What I simply want to do is to show the groups with its person in a ListBox, where the group name of the list groups equals the Name Property of my class "Groups".

I've tried with a CollectionViewSource bound to the "Collection". The groups are shown correct, but the items of the list are equal to the group names. So each group has only one item: its group name.

Many examples here show the grouping of items with only one collection. What I can do is to set the group name as Property of "Person". But then I can't count (and that is really neccessary):
 - how many persons are in each group
 - how many of that persons have the "Status" "Online".

I use linq in the "Group" class to count that.
Thanks for any advice helping me to get started.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, I am not sure if this is what you want achieve but here is a way that you can try:

Assuming your classes are like these:

```
public class Group
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsOnline { get; set; }
}
```

You can set `ListBox.ItemTemplate` as another ListBox bind to Contacts property, like:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="groups" Source="{Binding}" >
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Name" />
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>

<DataTemplate x:Key="groupTemplate" DataType="Group">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groups}}">
    <ListBox.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource groupTemplate}" />
    </ListBox.GroupStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="Contact">
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="Contact">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

You have to style the inner listbox a little bit.

**Edit**: Another solution by using `TreeView`

```
<DataTemplate DataType="Contact">
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
</DataTemplate>

<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groups}}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="Group" ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: This is quiet helpful and equal to my old solution, where I had an Expander per group and a ListBox for the Contacts. The problem here is, that you can select a person per list, but I supposed you can do it with one. I try to copy the UI of the Windows Live Messenger 2009 contact list. I think they used only one ListBox and an Expander as ControlTemplate for the group. But I also assume, they defined the group as property. But I really don't know, how they can count the online persons. By the way, you are right with your classes.

Comment: Why don't you use TreeView control for displaying hierarchical data?

Comment: You are absolutely right! I think, that would solve my problem for sure. I've got no answer for the "why". I haven't used the TreeView control a lot. But this would be the best for my problem. Thanks!

Comment: TreeView was really that what I needed.

Answer (score 9):

If you have a copy of [Programming WPF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596510373), jump to Page 221. If not I'll summarize (in my inept sort of way)

First you don't need to manually group the Person objects.

If each Person object has a Group property,

```
People people = // retrieve the List<Person> somehow
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(people);
view.GroupDescriptions.Add( new PropertyGroupDescription("Group") );
```

All controls that derive from ItemsControl can display grouped items, so

```
// the XAML
<ListBox ... ItemsSource={Binding}>
  <ListBox.GroupStyle>
    <x:Static Member="GroupStyle.Default" />
  </ListBox.GroupStyle>
</ListBox>
```

You can also define a custom GroupStyle and specify the GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate to define a new DataTemplate that shows custom attributes like 'some PropertyValue (Count)' - Bind the one TextBlock to `{Binding SomeProperty}` and the other to `{Binding ItemCount}`

HTH

Comment: Thanks, first. My Person object does NOT have a group property, yet. I'd like to avoid it. I did not understand how I can handle the count (only the logic, the fact with the TextBlock is clear).

Here is some code, if it might help you.

enum OnlineStatus { ONLINE, OFFLINE }

class Person {
  // The header of each group should count
  // how many Person exists with OnlineStatus "Online".
  public OnlineStatus Status { get; set; }
}

class Group {
  public List<Person> Persons = new List<Person>();
}

class Window1 {
  public List<Group> Groups = new List<Group>;
}

Comment: +1, `{Binding ItemCount}` was the answer I needed! THANK YOU!